# IIS KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, iis

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Захожу на сайт и получаю ошибку

```
GET http://mysite.ru/Home/Chart 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:8720
ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:8150
(anonymous) @ (index):106
fire @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:3062
fireWith @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:3174
ready @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:447
completed @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:118
```

В логах системы вижу ошибку:

```
Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-4-132433200981483300 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.ru\ 
    Machine name: WIN-TKJJDB6QT86 
 
Process information: 
    Process ID: 192 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\mysite.ru 
 
Exception information: 
    Exception type: KeyNotFoundException 
    Exception message: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

В какую сторону копать, что за ошибка?

Comment: За два года (читала комментарии ниже) что сайт стоял обновилась версия IIS установите нужные sdk пакеты обновленные по версии iis

Answer (score 2):

Код ответа `500 Internal Server Error` - означает, что сервер столкнулся с какой-либо ошибкой, которую он не может никак обработать.

Посмотрите на код, который обрабатывает этот запрос. Возможно там есть какие-либо ошибки?

Если верить вашим логам, то вы в коде обращаетесь к словарю, в котором нет ключа, который вы хотите получить. `Exception message: The given key was not present in the dictionary.` - Данный ключ отсутствует в словаре

Comment: Данный ключ отсутствует в словаре. - не понятен термин.. В каком словаре и какой ключ отсутствует? Просто в веб разработке не силен. А человек который раньше писал этот сайт, уже ничего не сможет рассказать..

Comment: @Amilman, можно нескромный вопрос, в какой разработке Вы сильны?

Comment: @V-Mor, до сих пор пишу на Delphi небольшие приложения для предприятия..)

Comment: @Amilman это никак не связано с web-разработкой, словарь - это самое базовое, что есть в языках программирования. Это тип данных, точно также как строка или число

Comment: @V-Mor, также и этот сайт писался моим коллегой для нужд предприятия. Но спросить что не так с сайтом уже не могу. Коллега умер.

Comment: @Inventor, спасибо за пояснение. Самое интересное сайт никто не трогал уже как года два. Но тут решили зайти на него и получаем такую ошибку. На самом сервере изменений не происходило.. Может зависеть от версии Net.Framework данная ошибка?

Comment: @Amilman ваше объяснение похоже на: "у меня машина сломалась, это может быть связано с выходом из строя катушки зажигания?" Да откуда я знаю в чём там проблема? Это ошибка может быть вызвана чем угодно, нужно смотреть на код

Comment: @Inventor, Да весь сайт состоит уже из скомпилированных dll и немного cshtml файлов. Как таковых исходников нет.. И уже не будет..

Comment: @Amilman тогда никак не исправить

Comment: @Amilman берите ILSpy и декомпилируйте. А там уже как повезёт, удачи (она вам понадобится).

Comment: @Inventor, эх жаль.. просто интересно. сайт работал, но через два года перестал.. Хотя ни каких изменений не было..

Comment: @ Pavel Mayorov, Спасибо. Тоже уже подумал про ILSpy

Comment: @Amilman может она и раньше появлялась при определённых условиях?

Comment: @Inventor, на то время сайтом пользовались очень часто и такой ошибки не замечалось. Причем данная ошибка проявляется только на главной странице сайта. На остальных либо не используется java либо там все хорошо..